# How to make markers larger in google street view

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I was wondering how/if it was possible to make marker icons appear larger than the default in google maps street view. (they currently show up really small/hard to see.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a larger icon (pixel-wise) and also set the `size` of the icon and/or `scaledSize` via the `MarkerImage` class.

Here is a quick and dirty example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AdnGH/

Here is the relevant documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage